# Numerical approximation by hand of arctan?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, numerical-methods

Is there any numerical method I can use by hand to solve an equation with $\arctan$?

I have for instance:
$$
2x\frac{180^\circ}{\pi}+\arctan(2x)=150^\circ 
$$
Or in radians:
$$
2x+\arctan(2x)=\frac{5\pi}{6} 
$$

Update:

With "by hand" I mean without a computer, just with pen, paper and a simple calculator.

Comment: Might I guess that instead of $\frac{180}{\pi}$ you mean $\frac{180^∘}{\pi}=1$? So that the equation you want to solve is $$2x+\arctan(2x)=\frac{5\pi}6?$$

Comment: And what do you mean "by hand"? You are asking this using some kind of computer, there is surely a calculator app available, probably a spreadsheet program or even some scripting language.

Comment: @LutzL Thanks for the comment, I updated my question. I mean in radians. "By hand" I mean without computer, just with pencil, paper and a simple calculator.

Comment: @Gae.S. Thanks for the comment, I updated my question.

Comment: So you can evaluate the arcus tangent with the required precision, no need to approximate that operation.

Answer (score 3):

By inspection or graphing, you could notice that the function
$$f(x)=2x+\tan^{-1}(2x)-\frac{5\pi}6$$ has a zero close to $x=\frac \pi 4$.

So, using Taylor around this point
$$f(x)=\left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)-\frac{\pi
   }{3}\right)+\left(2+\frac{8}{4+\pi ^2}\right) \left(x-\frac{\pi
   }{4}\right)+O\left(\left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)^2\right)$$ Ignoring the higher order terms, then an *approximation* is given by
$$x =\frac \pi 4+\frac{\left(4+\pi ^2\right) \left(\pi -3 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi
   }{2}\right)\right)}{6 \left(8+\pi ^2\right)}\approx 0.802207 $$ while the "exact" solution (using Newton method for example) would be $0.802264$.

This expansion gives the first iterate $x_1$ of Newton method starting with $x_0=\frac \pi 4$

Comment: Hi! How did you get the fraction? Did you use you first equation $f(\frac{\pi}{4})=2\frac{\pi}{4}+\arctan(2\frac{\pi}{4})-\frac{5\pi}{6}$ and set this equal to your Taylor expansion? And then solved for $x$?

Comment: @JDoeDoe. This is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The arcus tangent is nicely contractive, so that you can implement a fixed-point iteration
$$
x_{n+1}=\frac{5\pi}{12}-\frac12\arctan(2x_n)
$$
or perhaps faster
$$
y_{n+1}=\frac{5\pi}{24}-\frac14(\arctan(2y_n)-2y_n)
$$

```
n         x[n]                y[n]
-------------------------------------------
0   0                    0
1   1.3089969389957472   0.6544984694978736
2   0.7060332431802475   0.752140005235548
3   0.8316968384319999   0.7845414589967162
4   0.7942423418675012   0.7959216264499483
5   0.8045241611000699   0.7999849417244675
6   0.8016327513150959   0.8014438024522397
7   0.8024404675180803   0.8019685994905568
8   0.8022144096420561   0.8021575161901173
9   0.802277644078177    0.8022255394660307
10  0.8022599531289171   0.802250034816955
11  0.8022649022817598   0.802258855938407
12  0.8022635177097004   0.8022620325855991
13  0.8022639050555177   0.802263176559147
14  0.8022637966921317   0.8022635885272917
```

This is both not really converging fast, so one might apply some convergence accelerating measure like Atkins delta-squared process. Or construct some iteration that is more Newton like based on $x_0=1$.
\begin{align}
f(x)&=2x+\arctan(2x)-\frac{5\pi}6\\
f'(x)&=2+\frac2{1+4x^2}\\
x_{n+1}&=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_0)}=\frac{0.4x_n-\arctan(2x_n)+\frac{5\pi}6}{2.4}
\end{align}

```
 n       x[n]
 --------------------
 0  1
 1  0.796185483415585
 2  0.8026755902275313
 3  0.8022364873312032
 4  0.8022656372442502
 5  0.8022636996224416
 6  0.802263828406928
 7  0.8022638198471882
 8  0.8022638204161163
 9  0.8022638203783021
10  0.8022638203808156
11  0.8022638203806486
12  0.8022638203806596
13  0.8022638203806589
14  0.8022638203806589
```

or go full Newton, but that requires more effort for a single step.

Answer (score 1):

Writing the equation in the form $x = \frac{5\pi}{12}-\frac 12 \arctan(2x$), you realize that, considering the possibles values of $\arctan(\cdot)$, any solution must be in the interval $[\frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{2 \pi}{3}]$. So, take an initial guess in that interval, for instance $x_0=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and use newton's method
$$
x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{2 x_n + \arctan (2x_n)-\frac{5 \pi}{6}}{2+\frac{2}{1+(2x_n)^2}} 
$$

this way you get $x_3 = 0.802264$ (only the last digit is not correct).

Answer (score 0):

A relative simple, yet fairly accurate, analytic solution is given by

$$x=\frac{10}{57} + \frac{89}{228}\left(\frac{5\pi}{6}-\tan^{-1}\frac85\right)=0.802263$$

which can be derived by hand with a perturbation approximation.